# Image Trail Script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cursor

I have the following script for a cursor trail, however the cursor image is appearing in the top left corner of the page and is not appearing as the cursor trail? 
What could be causing the script not to function correctly?  I copied this script from:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/trailer.htm

I have tried editing the image paths(I originally used absolute paths to the images), I also tried disabling a previously used "plugin" which I was using for this trail

```
<script>
/******************************************
* Cross browser cursor trailer script- By Brian Caputo (bcaputo@icdc.com)
* Visit Dynamic Drive (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/) for full source code
* Modified Dec 31st, 02' by DD. This notice must stay intact for use
******************************************/

A=document.getElementById
B=document.all;
C=document.layers;
T1=new Array("wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat1.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/07/meerkat2.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat3.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat4.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat5.gif",77,39,"wp-content/uploads/2012/10/meerkat6.gif",77,39)

var offsetx=15 //x offset of trail from mouse pointer
var offsety=10 //y offset of trail from mouse pointer

nos=parseInt(T1.length/3)
rate=50
ie5fix1=0;
ie5fix2=0;
rightedge=B? document.body.clientWidth-T1[1] : window.innerWidth-T1[1]-20
bottomedge=B? document.body.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight-T1[2] : window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight-T1[2]

for (i=0;i<nos;i++){
createContainer("CUR"+i,i*10,i*10,i*3+1,i*3+2,"","<img src='"+T1[i*3]+"' width="+T1[(i*3+1)]+" height="+T1[(i*3+2)]+" border=0>")
}

function createContainer(N,Xp,Yp,W,H,At,HT,Op,St){
with (document){
write((!A && !B) ? "<layer id='"+N+"' left="+Xp+" top="+Yp+" width="+W+" height="+H : "<div id='"+N+"'"+" style='position:absolute;left:"+Xp+"; top:"+Yp+"; width:"+W+"; height:"+H+"; ");
if(St){
if (C)
write(" style='");
write(St+";' ")
}
else write((A || B)?"'":"");
write((At)? At+">" : ">");
write((HT) ? HT : "");
if (!Op)
closeContainer(N)
}
}

function closeContainer(){
document.write((A || B)?"</div>":"</layer>")
}

function getXpos(N){
if (A)
return parseInt(document.getElementById(N).style.left)
else if (B)
return parseInt(B[N].style.left)
else
return C[N].left
}

function getYpos(N){
if (A)
return parseInt(document.getElementById(N).style.top)
else if (B)
return parseInt(B[N].style.top)
else
return C[N].top
}

function moveContainer(N,DX,DY){
c=(A)? document.getElementById(N).style : (B)? B[N].style : (C)? C[N] : "";
if (!B){
rightedge=window.innerWidth-T1[1]-20
bottomedge=window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight-T1[2]
}
c.left=Math.min(rightedge, DX+offsetx);
c.top=Math.min(bottomedge, DY+offsety);
}
function cycle(){
//if (IE5) 
if (document.all&&window.print){
ie5fix1=document.body.scrollLeft;
ie5fix2=document.body.scrollTop;
}
for (i=0;i<(nos-1);i++){
moveContainer("CUR"+i,getXpos("CUR"+(i+1)),getYpos("CUR"+(i+1)))
}
}

function newPos(e){
moveContainer("CUR"+(nos-1),(B)?event.clientX+ie5fix1:e.pageX+2,(B)?event.clientY+ie5fix2:e.pageY+2)
}

function getedgesIE(){
rightedge=document.body.clientWidth-T1[1]
bottomedge=document.body.scrollHeight-T1[2]
}

if (B){
window.onload=getedgesIE
window.onresize=getedgesIE
}

if(document.layers)
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
document.onmousemove=newPos
setInterval("cycle()",rate)
</script>
```

Comment: This needs some cleanup.  Can you provide specifics of a) what you're expecting the script to do, b) what it's doing, c) what browser you're using, c) what you've tried to fix?

Comment: @saml sure.  a)i am expecting the script to display the cursor trail as done on http://www.nkangalodge.co.za/     b)it is showing the cursor "image" in the top left corner of the page, and not attaching to the mouse pointer as a trail.  c)Google Chrome.  d)I have tried editing the image paths(I originally used absolute paths to the images), I also tried disabling a previously used "plugin" which I was using for this trail

Comment: This one works in my Fx http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/trailer.htm but stops working when I copy it and change the images http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QsxKw/